# eventOverlap movingEvent doesn't update

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

#### Reduced Test Case

I tried to create a very simple codePen : https://codepen.io/crevecoeur/pen/RwZzRKm

#### Bug Description

Describe how to recreate the bug.
I create some events and a simple fullcalendar :
`eventOverlap: (stillEvent, movingEvent) => { stillEvent.setAllDay(false) movingEvent?.setAllDay(false) return true }`

What do you expect to happen?
I want the to change the moving event and the still event

What happens instead?
The still event change but not the moving event

#### ScreenShot

All Day Event : movingEvent
Long Event : stillEvent
[image: 2]
After i drag the event from Mon 01 to Mon 08

All Day Event : **not changed**

Long Event : changed
[image: 1]

Comment: I would expect this is because `stillEvent` doesn't get re-rendered at this time in the process (and why should it? It's not supposed to be moving!). If you want to update its properties and have that reflect on the page you'd need to cause all the events to be re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment
You wanted to say moveEvent ?
I will search in the direction of calendar.rerenderEvents()

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread what you were saying. If we are talking about movingEvent then my comment does not make much sense! In fullCalendar 5 there is no `rerenderEvents` function. As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4 you can try using calendar.render() instead.

Comment: So now I understand it properly. I wonder if the issue is because actually the movingEvent data is copied (internally within fullCalendar), and the version later supplied to the [eventDrop](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop) callback, and used to place the moved event back on the calendar, isn't the original (as changed by your setAllDay command). This demo suggests that might be the case: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abygwQR

Comment: It would make more sense though surely to manipulate the event's properties after it's finished being dragged, anyway? Why do you want to change the property while it's overlapping with another event? And why do you want to change the property of an event just because another event was dragged over the top of it? I'm not sure I understand the use case for what you're trying to do.

Comment: 1 - I'm using eventOverlap to only have two events on the same date
2 - When i have more than one event i want their duration to be half a day

Comment: But the flaw in that logic is that if you move the event past where the overlap occurs, so that it's no longer on the same day as the stillEvent, then the stillEvent doesn't need to be changed. However you are never changing back the stillEvent, so you end up with events being changed to half-day which didn't need to be, and you have no way of referencing it afterwards to change it back - unless perhaps you write extra code and keep a separate list yourself, and deal with that during eventDrop.

Comment: A better plan might be simply to handle eventDrop, then use getEvents, find all the events whose date range overlaps the date range on which the event was dropped, and set them to half-day. Or if there are already too many events on the date, use the revert() callback to cancel the drag-and-drop action. But even then, you'd still have odd cases where it may not behave as you'd expect, or maybe you haven't really thought about what should happen - like the "long event" in your example, it gets changed to one half-day, when before it was 3 whole days...is that really what you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks for the talk @ADyson ! i found the solution for my use case (a bit hacky).
It's close to your description.
I use **eventOverlap** for not more than two events.
I use **eventDrop** and iterate through all events.
I only have one day or less events.

Comment: eventOverlap can't tell you how many events there are in a day. It can only tell you whether two events overlap in time or not. e.g. If there are two half-day events on the same day already, eventOverlap can't tell you that.

Comment: Yes you're right i use **getEvents()** and iterate to know how many events i have the same day.

Comment: Ok. You seemed to be saying you were trying to use eventOverlap for that purpose.